# Download speed drops to 0 using Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, download

I have an `Nginx` server (File Sharing Server), and I'm having a weird issue.

I have downloaded a file multiple times (not just me),
And something weird is happening sometimes. The download speed dropped to `0 kbps` in the middle of the download (and the download won't continue anymore). But most of the times the download was ok.

This server is supposed to handle a lot of download connections of large files (up to `10 GB`), so it's a really big problem.

** Notice **

1. I'm sure that the problem is on the server, because it didn't happen only to me
2. I have another servers with the same specs that running `Apache`, and they can handle with 2K connections of downloads (large files).
3. The server needs to handle with a lot of connections.

**Server HW**

```
CPU: 12cores
RAM: 48GB
NGINX: 1.6 Version
Speed Port: 10GBPS Unmeterd
```

- [default.conf](http://pastebin.com/i046An1Y)
- [nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/7Ue7pZ2c)
- [sysctl.conf](http://pastebin.com/CELKWpgL)
- [www.conf](http://pastebin.com/21N35bv4)